# Conectar mi base de datos de Mongodb con python

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, nosql

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en el cual estoy haciendo uso de bases de datos y decidi usar MongoDB. para usar mongo con python uso Pymongo, hasta ahí todo bien, estoy viendo un video y a la hora de conectar con la base de datos el video solo muestra el acceso a una base de datos local, cuando yo tengo un cluster con atlas, está online y haciendo  uso de Studio3T he añadido elementos a distintas colecciones de prueba. aqui muestro las bases de datos que aparecen en local host

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost')
print (client.list_database_names())
```

El resultado de la consola es el siguiente:

```
"C:\Users\Satellite C655\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:/Users/Satellite C655/Desktop/Python/dotpy/dotpy/login sencillo/data.py"
['admin', 'config', 'local']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Entonces yo supuse que si en client poniamos 'localhost' porque en el video se estaba usando una base de datos local, si yo ponia el nombre de mi db se conectaba pero no se como hacer eso. Y necesito conectarme a mi cluster en atlas donde tengo mi base de datos y mis colecciones. (PD, desde el mismo pycharm me conecto a la consola de mongodb y puedo ver que en efecto mi base de datos está online)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conectar tu aplicación (script) con tu clúster debes generar un enlace (o cadena)
en la página de tu cluster en [MongoDb Atlas](https://account.mongodb.com/account/login) Y haces lo siguiente:

1. clic en 'Connect'
2. Seleccionas la Opción 'Connect your application'
3. Seleccionas el lenguaje Python en la opción 'DRIVER'
4. Seleccionas la version de Python que usas o la más cercana

¡Listo! te dan un enlace parecido a este `mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-url>/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority` solo tienes que reemplazar `<username>` y `<password>` por los datos del usuario de tu clúster. En caso que no tengas creado o no recuerdes la contraseña del usuario puedes crear o generar una nueva contraseña fácilmente en la Opción 'Database Access' del Clúster.

Ahora en tu script hace lo siguiente:

```py
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient('EL ENLACE GENERADO')
db = client.test
```

Como es primera vez es posible que te salten algunos errores de modulos como pymongo o dnspython, en ese caso, solo instálalos y listo!

```
pip install pymongo
pip install dnspython
```

Para información más detallada sobre este proceso visita:
https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/pymongo/ o
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/